# Enable function auto-complete in Aptana Studio for returned objects

Tags: php, aptana

I'm using the eclipse plugin of Aptana Studio and I've set the primary project nature to PHP. For some reason there are no auto complete suggestions for returned objects. For example:

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$db->... //auto complete suggestions are listed
$var = $db->prepare(...); //returns a PDOStatement
$var->... //no auto complete suggestions
```

Is it possible to enable the auto complete suggestions for returned objects?